# Which transparent plastic to use for electrolysis of dilute sulphuric acid

Tags: electrolysis, materials, plastics

I plan to do an experiment which involves the electrolysis of dilute sulfuric acid (1 M or 1 mol/L). I would like to carry it out in a long transparent plastic container (easier to handle and clean). What would be the suitable plastic for this?

Comment: Just curious, why not use glass since it’s already transparent and inert with sulfuric acid? And probably also easier to clean than plastic?

Comment: The problem is that I need a pretty big 'tub' or container for this experiment, and I imagine that this will take too much weight. And also I'm not sure were I would find a deep rectangular glass container, at least where I live.

Comment: At 1 M, most plastic containers, such as polyethylene (polythene, in the Old World), polypropylene (better at high temps and a bit more transparent), acrylic or polycarbonate should be usable for at least a few days' use.